# Hover on text link changes z-index of an image

Tags: html, css, hover, z-index, mousehover

I have a list of projects as regular text links and a group of images wildy and offset stacked on top of each other, they should overlap a bit but not completely cover each other. They are either placed in a fixed spot or randomly placed on each load, whatever is easier. Each text link should be "connected" (not linked!) to one of these images. When you hover over one of the text links the "connected" image should pop to the front.

I tried out a few tutorials and looked through a few dozen examples and actually managed to get the basic code to work, but now my images are all exactly on top of each other while I want them to be shifted a bit.

I have no idea how to fix this although I'm pretty sure it's quite easy to fix. :(

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet2.css">
<title>TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="switcher-wrapper">

<ul>

    <li><a id="eins" href="#"><span>projekt 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a id="zwei" href="#"><span>projekt 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a id="drei" href="#"><span>projekt 3</span></a></li>

</ul>

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#switcher-wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    margin:20px 20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
#switcher-wrapper a {
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#eins {
    background:url(01.jpg);
    top:300px;
}
#zwei { 
    background:url(03.jpg);
}
#drei { 
    background:url(04.jpg);

}
#switcher-wrapper a span {
    position:absolute;
}
#eins span {
    left:0;
    bottom:-135px; 
}
#zwei span {
    left:0;
    bottom:-155px; 
}
#drei span {
    left:0;
    bottom:-175px; 
}
#switcher-wrapper a:hover {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Here's my code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5gcwofmk/

Comment: can you expand on how you would want them shifted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in your code you are trying to alter the `top` of `#eins` element *after* you declared the rules for `#switcher-wrapper a`. You need to adhere to the scope/precedence you've created with your rules. You can read about specificity in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Because `#eins` is an `a` tag; `#switcher-wrapper a` actually takes precedence over `#eins` even if `#eins` is declared *after* `#switcher-wrapper a`.

You can correct this by add `a` tags before your `id`s like so:

```
a#eins {
  /* rules */
}
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gcwofmk/1/). I've 'shifted' the images a bit, but unsure how you wanted them to look so it's just random.

```css
#switcher-wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    margin:20px 20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
#switcher-wrapper a {
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
a#eins {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/qBuL8TO.jpg);
    left: 40px;
    top: 20px;
}
a#zwei { 
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/ddZrGHK.jpg);
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
a#drei { 
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/39TnFyv.jpg);
}
#switcher-wrapper a span {
    position:absolute;
}
#eins span {
    left:0;
    bottom:-135px; 
}
#zwei span {
    left:0;
    bottom:-155px; 
}
#drei span {
    left:0;
    bottom:-175px; 
}
#switcher-wrapper a:hover {
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="switcher-wrapper">

<ul>

 <li><a id="eins" href="#"><span>projekt 1</span></a></li>
 <li><a id="zwei" href="#"><span>projekt 2</span></a></li>
 <li><a id="drei" href="#"><span>projekt 3</span></a></li>

</ul>

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yes, that's pretty much what I wanted in the first place. How could I get text links to stay in an ordered list? They "shifted" with the images. Is there any chance to "unlink" the text links and the images? Thanks so much!

Comment: When you say unlink, you mean remove the hyperlink from the text? You can't with your current `html` structure, you would have to rebuild your elements; the text is nested inside an `<a>` element - you could however, unstyle the links

Comment: Okay, "unlink" is probably the wrong word. What I'd really want is for the text links to stay in an ordered <li> list while the images are placed randomly. Does that make sense? I'm horrible at explaining these things, I'm sorry.

Comment: @dnz sometimes it is hard to find the right words to describe an issue; I can totally relate to that:) - I think I understand what you're asking, *yes* it is totally possible, but it *does* require you to alter your element structure, but completely do-able (I would create a new question for it if you need help) - also don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you; you have no obligation to do this, but it helps the community know that you found an acceptable solution to the question you've asked

Comment: You helped me out a ton! Thanks so much! I'm definitely close to what I want to achieve. I'm trying to get the rest to work. Could you maybe point me in the direction of an possible guide on how to alter the structure? I have absolutely no idea how and where to start. Thanks again! Accepting the answer now and upvoting as much as I can.

Comment: It seems to me like you want stacked images, with links that when `hovered` display one of the images? is this correct? So essentially, leave the links as `li` items, but the images won't necessarily be in the `li`?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I want!

Comment: @dnz not exactly sure how to do it with pure css, but with a little jQuery [you can do it like this](http://jsfiddle.net/21m70bhb/)